# Python: I've got some Problems with pandas (tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str)

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to compare hash values in a .csv-file with the three columns image_url, code and hash.
For a start i just tried to print the hash values from the rows which have code = 1.

This is my code to get the dataframe with all the rows i need

```
readpath = os.path.join(folder,readfile)
df = pd.read_csv(readpath)
df_code1 = df[df["code"] == 1]
```

but now the problems begin to start

```
for row in df_code1.iterrows():
    try:
        print(row['hash'])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

prints `tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str` over and over.. when i use `df_code1.rows:` instead i get the Errormessage 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'rows'

I'm pretty sure i imported everything correctly.

May anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: sample data please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas

Answer (score 2):

First I think the best is avoid use [DataFrame.iterrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-pandas-iterrows-have-performance-issues/24871316#24871316).

> Generally, iterrows should only be used in very, very specific cases.

---

Here is problem [`DataFrame.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) return 2 values:

> **index** label or tuple of label
> The index of the row. A tuple for a MultiIndex.

> **data** Series
> The data of the row as a Series.

So if assign output to `row` get tuples:

```
for row in df_code1.iterrows():
    print (row)
```

So you can assign output to 2 variables:

```
for i, row in df_code1.iterrows():
    print (row)
```

Or select second value of tuple:

```
for row in df_code1.iterrows():
    print (row[1])
```

Comment: nice that is working, thanks

but why is df_code1.rows: telling me the 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'rows'? I am sure i did this once with a dataFrame and that worked

Comment: @lxg95 - I think it is not valid pandas value.